# How to display all the test cases in test explorer in Protractor Cucumber Node JS framework

Tags: protractor, cucumber, test-runner, test-explorer

Hi I'm working in protractor cucumber node js framework. Im using VS code for it.Do we have any test explorer or test runner which can display all my test cases and I can just run by a click? Similar to test explorer in Visual Studio. Currently am running scripts to run the test cases either using tags or just npm test. We have more projects in same framework.SO we will have more Test cases. So  a test explorer to list the TCs will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question and found no solution in cucumber or protractor, but ended up using bash `find . -name "*.feature"`.